# How to approach navigation for an iOS app with sub-areas/routes

Tags: ios, objective-c, uinavigationcontroller

I'm new to objective-c/iOS development and am struggling to find guidance on how to structure navigation given an app menu structure such as:

- **Home**

  - Start order
  - Select store
  - Select category
  - Add item to basket
  - Checkout etc.
- **My Account**

  - Edit/Add addresses
  - Update profile etc.
- **Order History**

  - View Order
- **etc.**

I'm using [ECSlidingViewController](https://github.com/ECSlidingViewController/ECSlidingViewController) to display the navigation menu (i.e. the top level nav is hidden and not displayed ala tab bar controller).

I'm from a web development background, so I'm used to individual views having a route (URL) and being able to load up any route from anywhere.

I think I understand how to use UINavigationController (or at least I think I do) to handle sequential navigation such as (home > start order > select store etc.) where back (pop) makes sense, but I'm a little worried that I'm missing something with respect to unstructured navigation.

For example, if I'm on the checkout view (a few controllers deep in the home navigation hierarchy), and I decide to tap menu (menu slides out) and select My Account, fiddle with my details, then tap menu and home, I would expect to land back where I was before I navigated to My Account (i.e. on the checkout page).

What is the standard practice for this type of navigation? I was looking at libraries such as [routable-ios](https://github.com/clayallsopp/routable-ios) but don't have enough experience to make a call as to whether this is a decent approach or not.

---

I have considered the following approach:

1. Maintain a high level UINavigationController which maintains an array of sub-UINavigationControllers, i.e. [HomeNavigationController, AccountNavigationController, OrderHistoryNavigationController]
2. To start, the main navigation controller would load up HomeNavigationController which points to "Home" as the root view and the user would progress through an order process where push/pop works as expected.
3. If the user tapped My Account, I would reset the main navigation controller array to the account navigation controller (account view controller would be the root) and the user would continue there. I would keep a handle on the HomeNavigationController so that that the position of the user is maintained should they tap Menu, Home (i.e. I would reset the Main Navigation Controller back to the HomeNavigationController reference where the stack would be in the state before they tapped My Account).

Are there any reasons why this is a poor approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I use ECSlidingViewController, usually it's easiest to assign Storyboard IDs to each view controller. That way, when you select a specific item in the menu, you can present the view controller based upon the storyboard ID as follows:

```
UIViewController *newTopVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"topViewController"];

CGRect frame = self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame;
self.slidingViewController.topViewController = newTopViewController;
self.slidingViewController.topViewController.view.frame = frame;
[self.slidingViewController resetTopView];
```

This is an example I had from previous versions of ECSlidingViewController, but the general concept should be the same. You just need to make sure the view controller you want to present has the same identifier that you specify in code. You can find the identifier within the storyboard... select the view controller and look in the Identity Inspector. There will be an "Identity" section with "Storyboard ID" listed.

If you choose to use nib files instead of storyboard, you can replace the first line with the following:

```
UIViewController *newTopVC = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"TopViewController" bundle: nil];
```

If you go this route, the view controllers you instantiate from the menu could themselves be the Navigation Controllers for the different menu items, that way the user can progress through and back within that menu feature as expected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should have outlined in my question that I'm not using storyboards. That said, I think what you've outlined in conceptually quite similar to the approach I was thinking of taking in my question.

Comment: Oh, okay! Yes then if you aren't using storyboards, instead of the first line you could instead load the nib file you wish to use. I'll update the answer just so it's there as well.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest problem I see with this approach is the complexity in keeping track of your controllers (your bullet point 3.) This could get ugly.

Also, Apple is quite adamant that the slider menu is a bad idea. Not that you have to accept Apple's opinion on this, but it's something to consider.

A common way to handle this kind of navigation is to use a UITabController. See for example the "iTunes Store" app or even the "Phone" app.

I have used the tab bar to segment different feature sets, with some tabs containing UINavigationControllers. I think it is very effective.

The tabs allow users to switch easily between parts of your app without necessarily losing their place. Each tab stays in memory and you don't need to write logic to swap view controllers when the tab changes.

Of course, you still need to consider how changes a user makes when switching to a different tab should affect the current tab when the user returns.

For example, if a user is in the order tab making a purchase and then switches to the account tab to sign in, does that affect the order process when the user returns to the order tab? Perhaps you should offer a simplified sign-in view within the order process so the user doesn't have to switch to a different tab.

These are things you will need to consider no matter which navigation approach you take. My recommendation, though, is to take a good look at the UITabController and see if it works for you.

Comment: Thanks Mike, your point is valid. We considered the use of the slider menu very carefully. We already have a web version of the app, and understand how users use it. The process is fairly linear during the order process. We don't want to waste valuable real estate for functionality that is infrequently accessed. Given that you've indicated that the UITabController handles nav elegantly, I wonder if I could use it but hide it, where my slide out menu is a proxy for it (tapping a menu icon invokes the relevant tab). Thoughts?

Comment: My guess is if you are using the slider, you would be best off following @c_rath's advice below. Storyboards are a good idea, too.